# How do I create a hash from this array?

Tags: ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
["value1=3", "value2=4", "value3=5"]
```

I'd like to end up with a hash like:

```
H['value1'] = 3
H['value2'] = 4
H['value3'] = 5
```

There's some parsing involved and I was hoping to get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ary = ["value1=3", "value2=4", "value3=5"]

H = Hash[ary.map {|s| s.split('=') }]
```

This however will set all the values as strings `'5'` instead of integer. If you are sure they are all integers:

```
H = Hash[ary.map {|s| key, value = s.split('='); [key, value.to_i] }]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do as @BroiSatse suggests, but here's another way that uses a Regex:

```
ary = ["value1=3", "value2=4", "value3=5"]

ary.join.scan(/([a-z]+\d+)=(\d+)/).map { |k,v| [k,v.to_i] }.to_h
  => {"value1"=>3, "value2"=>4, "value3"=>5}
```

Here's what's happening:

```
str = ary.join
  #=> "value1=3value2=4value3=5"
a = str.scan(/([a-z]+\d+)=(\d+)/)
  #=> [["value1", "3"], ["value2", "4"], ["value3", "5"]]
b = a.map { |k,v| [k,v.to_i] }
  #=> [["value1", 3], ["value2", 4], ["value3", 5]]
b.to_h
  #=> {"value1"=>3, "value2"=>4, "value3"=>5}
```

For Ruby versions < 2.0, the last line must be replaced with

```
Hash[b]
  #=> {"value1"=>3, "value2"=>4, "value3"=>5}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation and step-by-step.